# Can I replace MC33204P with one of these other op amps?

Tags: led, audio, operational-amplifier

I'm working to make this [schematic](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2126272%20Schematic.pdf)
and I was wondering if it is possible to swap out the MC33204p with either LM348N or LM339AN. And if you could let me know why swapping them would still work I'd be greatful.

Comment: If you tell us what these opamps for, we can make good recommendations.

Comment: @Frank - The schematic says it's a LED color organ, so audio frequencies, not Hi-Fi.

Comment: @stevenvh I have missed that schematic link.. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Steven re the 33024 being superior to the 348 and that the LM339 is unsuitable (because it is a comparator and has different pinouts and has open collector outputs). The 348 could be made to work with some care but there is no point in doing so.

However the low cost and widely available [LM324 (quad) / LM358 (dual)](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/LM224.pdf) industry standard entry level workhorse op amp (does that sound dumbed down enough) should work well enough here and is pin for pin drop in compatible. Unlike the 33204 it is not quite rail to rail on input or output, and current output capability is much lower, but in this circuit neither aspect is liable to be significant.

Note that in the diagram they have used a TS921 as a "rail splitter" to make a half supply point. In this circuit you could achieve as good a result by removing the TS921 completely , joining where pin 3 and pin6 now are (V-Gnd to C15 top) and changing the 2 x 100k to 2 x 10k.

However, the MC33204 costs [$1.60 in 1's at Digikey](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=MC33204PGOS-ND) and is in stock. The LM324 costs less [from $0.44 in 1/s, 12 cents in zillions](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=LM324ADGOS-ND) , but the difference is minimal when all the other costs are considered.

Comment: Thanks, this is also very helpful. Thanks for dumbing it down a bit. I only ask because I have about 30 LM324s laying and I'm always trying to save all the money I can.

Answer (score 3):

The [LM339](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM139.pdf) absolutely not. That's a comparator, not an opamp, and it has an open collector output.

The [LM348](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM148.pdf) is a quad opamp like the [MC33204](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC33201-D.PDF), but has the specs of the LM741, and this is an age-old opamp with specs inferior to the MC33204's. You could probably replace the MC33204 with the LM348, but don't expect the same performance. An opamp has many parameters, and it's not easy, comparing two opamps, to pinpoint which one in a specific design will be better or worse overall. So, while the LM348 may work (just try it), I would stick with the original if possible.

**edit**
On second thought the LM348 may be usable. I only had a brief glance at the schematic and only saw that it worked with audio signals. Missed the LED color organ. For this you don't need a Hi-Fi opamp, like you would if the audio would ultimately go to a pair of speakers. The LM348 will be OK.